# Arduino IDE Display Code Line Numbers

Tags: arduino-ide

In the Arduino IDE: How can I get the line numbers shown in a sidebar of the editor?

It is hard to find which line my errors are referring to without them...

I am using Arduino IDE on a form of Windows.

Comment: @crabman84, how do you know that the the person who posted this question > 2 years ago was using Windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to **File > Preferences.** Under the **Settings** tab, click the checkbox for **Display line numbers**.

[image: Options in arduino ide to show the lines on the code]

Keep in mind that this option is available in the latest version of the Arduino Integrated Development Environment (v1.6.6). In case you are using GNU/Linux distribution is recomended to use the one that is **NOT** in the distribution's repositories but the one that is offered in https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software

If you are using a Linux OS this solution may not work. Look at the 'preferences.txt' where you can edit your preferences in a file without a GUI.It will display all possible options available for your current version of Arduino IDE on your OS. It is usually in the '.arduino' folder which may be in your 'home' folder.