# How to turn off the display of line numbers on Mac Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm trying to turn off line numbers on the Mac Arduino IDE but don't see the option for it after navigating to `Arduino IDE > Preferences`. Below is a screenshot of what I am seeing.

[image: Arduino Preferences]

I saw [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/52161/arduino-ide-display-code-line-numbers) asked previously, but there is no `File > Preferences` path on Mac. I am using Version 2.0.0 on macOS (10.14 or newer).

Comment: OT, just out of curiosity: Why do you want them to be off? For example, I cannot work without line numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see a proper place to do this in the 2.0.0 IDE preferences. However, modifying the .arduinoIDE/setting.json file to include `"editor.lineNumbers": "off",` seems to work.

```json
{
 "editor.lineNumbers": "off",
 "editor.fontSize": 14,
 ...
}
```

[image: Shows IDE 2.0.0 with and without line numbers.]

Edgar Bonet pointed out in a comment that there's still a bunch of empty space in that region. The image above doesn't do a good of showing why though. In the below screenshots I've told the IDE to set a breakout and hovered over where folding region so it displays the fold indicators to make somewhat easier to see that and compare what effect on width results from disabling these things.

If you want to save a bit more space you can add turn off the code folding feature, which removes the spaced that would be used for fold indicators with an additional `"editor.folding": "false",` in the settings.json file.

For comparison, here's everything enabled, numbers but no folding, folding but no numbers, no folding and no numbers:

[image: Comparison of widths with different combinations of folding and line number settings.]

I haven't yet found out how to turn off the display of break-point indicators. I assume that it is possible though.

Comment: Looks like it didn't remove from the layout the column dedicated to the line numbers: it's now just wasted space.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't get rid of the entire area they inhabit. That space is also used for the indicators for code folding and indicators for breakpoints. So the space is only narrowed so much by the removal of the line numbers themselves. Maybe, I'll look into seeing if there's a way to remove the entire area or what it looks like if told not to indicate breakpoints or folding.